# extract i18n validation messages in Cakephp 2 plugin

Tags: cakephp, plugins, internationalization, cakephp-2.4

I am developing a plugin in CakePHP 2.x, and I want to translate the error messages from the models.

I was reading the documentation, but its no clear about how extract exactly.

I changed the domain for my models with:

```
$validationDomain = 'validation_errors';
```

so cakephp made a validation_errors.pot file.

I have two folders, 'spa' and 'eng', with 'LC_MESSAGES' into them, and 'manager.po' file where I put the translations for my plugin (with the same name).

Where I have to make the .po file from validation_errors.pot? and how I have to name it?

Thanks!

Comment: Not 100% sure (that's why I didn't respond as an actual answer), but by inference probably you should put it on LC_MESSAGES folder in the respective language, and the name should be the same as your domain, in this case, "validation_errors". Please try it.

Comment: @Eagle I tried with your solution, but it didnt work. I tried putting the prefix 'Manager' (my plugin name): $validationDomain = 'Manager.validation_errors'; too. Any solution more?